# Setting parameter in SQL Server database

Tags: vb.net

I tired the following Query to access my SQL Server database.  It returns an error.

```
SELECT Name, Address, PhoneNo FROM dbo.tblContacts where name=?
```

Is something wrong with it?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use @nameOfTheParameter instead of ?

Check this http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/PassParameterintoSQLcommand.htm